# How to center a TextBlock inside a GridViewColumn? (Sample xaml included)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, layout

```
<Window x:Class="EffectsWindow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EffectsViewModel.Effects}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Effects">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       Text="{Binding Name}"
                                       TextAlignment="Center" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

</Window>
```

`Effect` is just a type has a Name property that returns a string, but the text is still not centered inside its cell.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can Stretch the `HorizontalContentAlignment` for `ItemContainerStyle`

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EffectsViewModel.Effects}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <!--...-->
</ListView>
```

**Update**

You should be able to combine the alternating row colors with `HorizontalContentAlignment` like this. I tried it and it seems to be working

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EffectsViewModel.Effects}"
          AlternationCount="2">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <!--...-->
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks but that code centers all ListViewItems, right? I just want some columns to be center, and others to be as-is (aligned to left).

Comment: @Joan Venge: It will center the columns where you set `HorizontalAlignment="Center"`, otherwise it will be left aligned (or whatever you specify)

Comment: Meleak, that works. Thanks, but there is a small problem. Basically I use this alternating colors: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/05/28/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-alternating-rows.aspx The first xaml example there, which also sets the style, so they don't seem work to work together. Is it possible to combine these?

Comment: @Joan Venge: Updated my answer. If I understood your question correctly that should work

Comment: Thanks Meleak, it works great. I was trying to see where I can fit your code in the existing alternating style but couldn't do it. Thanks for showing how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an app like [snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to visually inspect the properties of your app and you can see where things are not aligning like you expect.

Comment: Thanks I did but still didn't help me what cause it to be not centered.